# Data is not inserted into database

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi I have created a n SQLite database in android, in which **I have inserted two records initially**, but on executing the **data are not getting inserted** , **Database is showing empty**.Can anybody help me to insert data

giving my database class below

```
          public class DummyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{



   public static final int NAME_COLUMN=2;

   static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NestDatabase.db";
  static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
  static final String tableName="Employees";
  static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table      "   
           +           "  Employees  "+ " " + "  "
           +       "    (     "    
           +     "   ID   "  
           +     "     integer      primary key autoincrement ,    "   
           +      "             NAME            text     , 
             EMPLOYEE_CODE    text," 
           +      "    MOBILE_NUMBER    integer  ); ";



  public SQLiteDatabase db;
  private final Context context;
  public DataBaseHelper1 dbHelper;

  public DummyDatabase(Context _context) {
        super(_context,DATABASE_NAME, null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        context=_context;
        dbHelper=new DataBaseHelper1(_context,DATABASE_NAME, 
          null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


  public DummyDatabase open() throws SQLException
    {
        db=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        db.close();
    }

    public int deleteEntry(String NAME)
    {

           String where="NAME=?";
           int numberOFEntriesDeleted= db.delete("Employees", where, new String[]
           {NAME}) ;
           Toast.makeText(context, "Number fo Entry Deleted Successfully : 
             "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return numberOFEntriesDeleted;

    }
    public String getEntry(String Emp_code)
    {


            Cursor cursor=db.query("Employees", null, " EMPLOYEE_CODE=?", new
             String[]{Emp_code}, null, null, null);
            if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
                return "NOT EXIST";
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String user= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
            return user;


    }


      @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL("insert into Employees( NAME , EMPLOYEE_CODE , MOBILE_NUMBER)
            "+" values ('Alexander','A111','1234567890');");
    db.execSQL("insert into Employees( NAME , EMPLOYEE_CODE , MOBILE_NUMBER)
             "+" values ('Bernie','B111','1234567890');");
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.w("TaskDBAdapter","Upgrading from 
       version"+oldVersion+"to"+newVersion+",which will destroy all old data"); 

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+"TEMPLATE");
    onCreate(db);
   }

        }
```

Comment: Is there any error in your logcat ? if then please post your logcat also.

Comment: `SQLiteDatabase` has an `insert` method. It's better to use that method instead of using raw sql query.

Comment: Oncreate is called when db is created. Can you clear app cache and data before trying again?

Comment: I have edited my code but it is still not inserting data

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the data table in the `onCreate` method of SQLiteOpenHelper.

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DATABASE_CREATE;

**Change your insert statement** to

```
db.execSQL("insert into Employees( NAME , EMPLOYEE_CODE , MOBILE_NUMBER)
             VALUES ('Alexander','A111','1234567890');");
```

Comment: Did you change the insert statement??

Answer (score 1):

In onCreate first you have to create table like this :

```
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                    );
```

Edited :

```
public long createEntry(String name, String employeeCode, int mobileNum) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(NAME, name);
    cv.put(EMPLOYEE_CODE, employeeCode);
    cv.put(MOBILE_NUMBER, mobileNum);
    return db.insert("Employees", null, cv);
}
```

Call this method from oncreate and pass what you want to insert.

Comment: well Let me try ...this

Comment: I have created the table initially and it is called from another class's oncreate..so should I create table again in this oncreate?

Comment: Are you using Same Database Name and Table Name?

Comment: yes, but I have removed that now Database is creating in this class, and table is creating in this oncreate method , Please see the edit above..

Comment: Can I insert some values initially to table not like any dynamic insertion?

Comment: Yes when you call this method in onCreate than value will be inserted after creating table.

Comment: but by this method I need to insert values at some point during the working right ? If I am using this database fr just a user authentication purpose where ,  the new user is already in the database or not . So I must insert the records initially ...I have used similar codes for inserting into database but it is something like a sign up process , data enters on submit...

Comment: correct but at some point or initially you have to insert value in the db even in sign up process, than call this method from there.

Answer (score 1):

`onCreate` is called only the first time the database is created. So my guess is, that the database exists (from an earlier run of your code, probably without the inserts at this time) and the `onCreate`is simply not called. Just add a `Log.d()` in `onCreate` to check that. Also, just defining a `create table`is not enough, you also need to execute it against the database in `onCreate()` :-).

Going further there're a few things you should change in your code. One or the other could actually immediately solve your problem, too.

- `create table` and changes in the table structure (new tables, columns, views) should be done in `onCreate` and `onUpgrade`. This is the right place for structure changes and initial data like your inserts.
- Actually your `onCreate` should just contain the line `onUpgrade(db, 0, 1)` and you do everything in `onUpgrade`.
- If you run a statement like insert, update, delete (Data Manipulation Language: DML) you should always `commit` your work. Before that the data is not written to disk an in the next run you cannot select it any more.
- use `db.insert` when inserting rows instead of `db.execSQL`. It's meant to be the easier interface for Java-programmers.
- Make sure your code works with all status of the database. An upgrade to a new version of DB is only called once, so is `onCreate` is only called the first time you create the database and then never again! While in development this can be annoying because you have to delete the whole database before each test run with `context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME)`.

Answer (score 0):

check out create table query. m giving you one sample query.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS menus (menuname TEXT,screens TEXT,menuitem TEXT,menuposition TEXT,menuid TEXT,PRIMARY KEY(menuid));
```

and execute create table query before inserting. add above code in your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: hi Brijesh...thanks for the reply but It is not working..I have edited my code above please check..

Answer (score 0):

You Forgot to create TABLE. You need to execute DATABASE_CREATE query in OnCreate or (optional) UPDATE table in onUpgrade table. refer following code, see UPDATED and ADDED tags

..
SQLite says, primary key must be named _id

```
public class DummyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 2;
static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NestDatabase.db";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
static final String tableName = "Employees";
static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE employees (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, mobile_number TEXT);"; /** UPDATED **/


public SQLiteDatabase db;
private final Context context;
public DataBaseHelper1 dbHelper;

public DummyDatabase(Context _context) {
    super(_context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    context = _context;
    dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper1(_context, DATABASE_NAME,
            null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


public DummyDatabase open() throws SQLException {
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    db.close();
}

public int deleteEntry(String NAME) {
    String where = "NAME=?";
    int numberOFEntriesDeleted = db.delete("Employees", where, new String[]
            {NAME});
    Toast.makeText(context, "Number fo Entry Deleted Successfully : 
            "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return numberOFEntriesDeleted;

}

public String getEntry(String Emp_code) {
    Cursor cursor = db.query("Employees", null, " EMPLOYEE_CODE=?", new
            String[]{Emp_code}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() < 1) // UserName Not Exist
    {
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String user = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
    return user;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE); //** ADDED */
    db.execSQL("insert into Employees( NAME , EMPLOYEE_CODE , MOBILE_NUMBER)
            "+"values('Alexander', 'A111', '1234567890'); ");
    db.execSQL("insert into Employees( NAME , EMPLOYEE_CODE , MOBILE_NUMBER) 
            "+"values('Bernie', 'B111', '1234567890'); ");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look on this example

```
public class RouteDbAdapter 
{

public static final String KEY_PLACE = "place";
public static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";
public static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

private static final String TAG = "RouteDbAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;


private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table routes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "place text not null, latitude real not null, longitude real not null);";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cojDB";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "routes";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private final Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS routes");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}


public RouteDbAdapter(Context ctx) 
{
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

public RouteDbAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close()
{
    mDbHelper.close();
}

public long createPlace(String place, Double lat,Double lng) 
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_PLACE, place);
    initialValues.put(KEY_LATITUDE, lat);
    initialValues.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, lng);

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

public boolean deletePlace(String place) 
{

    return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_PLACE + "='" + place+"'", null) > 0;
}


 public Cursor fetchAllPlace()
 {
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_LATITUDE,
            KEY_LONGITUDE,KEY_PLACE}, null, null, null, null, null);
 }


    public Cursor fetchPlace(String place) throws SQLException 
    {

    Cursor mCursor = 
        mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_LATITUDE,KEY_LONGITUDE}, KEY_PLACE + "= '" +       place+"'", null,
                null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) 
    {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
 }
}
```